# Java recursion – exponentiation method

Tags: java, recursion, functional-programming, exp

I made the method exp in java but when I process the method I always get the same answer

```
public class Recursion {

    private double x;    
    private int n;

    // Method exp(x,n)

    public static double exp(double x,int n){

        if(n > 1){
         n = n-1;   
         x = x * x;
         exp(x,n);  
        }       
        else if (n == 1);
            return x;           
    }

    public static void main (String[]args){
        System.out.println(exp (2.5,4));
    }  
}
```

Comment: Well, what answer are you expecting?

Comment: you never use the value returned by `exp(x,n)`

Comment: what is with the line `else if (n == 1);`? i think the ; is wrong there...

Comment: public static double exp (double x, int n) {
if (n==0) return 1;
if (n==1) return x;
else return exp(x,n-1)*x;
}

Comment: did my answer solved your problem?